# Fetch all Calendars From Office 365 Calendar Account

Tags: rest, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

We need to fetch all Calendars in an office 365 calendar account

We basically make an api call to the endpoint
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[logged-in-user-id]/calendars](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%5Blogged-in-user-id%5D/calendars)

but it returns only 10 calendars (maximum) when we call the API !?

Any help/tips appreciated !

Comment: You can use $top query parameter to get 1 to 999 objects per page. By default every API has its own default pagination count. So you can simply use top query parameter or you can use `nextLink` which you get in the first API call and use it to get next set of results. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Moving this to answer. If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $top query parameter to get 1 to 999 objects per page. By default every API has its own default pagination count. So you can simply use top query parameter or you can use `nextLink` which you get in the first API call and use it to get next set of results. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Setting the max to 100 or more doesn't seem to work but using nextLink seems to work fine